# Database Initialization Running too late

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, unit-testing, ef-code-first

**EDITED**

I am running a unit test(using nunit) for a databsae initialization method. I set up the test and seed the database with a test example using this:

```
    [TestFixtureSetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        //select database
        Database.DefaultConnectionFactory = new SqlConnectionFactory(connectionString);
        database = new POSDatabaseContext(connectionString);

        //drop database and recreate
        string query = "ALTER DATABASE [POS] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;";
        database.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(TransactionalBehavior.DoNotEnsureTransaction, query);
        database.Database.Delete();
        database.Database.Create();

        //add seed value to test against
        database.Metadata.Add(new Metadata {
            ID = "META",
            IsInitialized = false,
            testBool = true,
            TimeCreated = DateTime.Now,
            TimeEdited = DateTime.Now
        });
        database.SaveChanges();
    }
```

I then run the test method which is this:

```
    [Test]
    public void InitializeDatabaseTestWithMatchingModel()
    {
        //set initializer for data context to test it, and run it
        Database.SetInitializer<POSDatabaseContext>(new
            CustomDropCreateDatabaseWithMatchingModelTest());
        database.Database.Initialize(true);

        //use the metadata table to check if it was run correctly
        //if metadata exist, which it should
        if(database.Metadata.Any(s => s.ID == "META"))
        {
            Metadata actual = database.Metadata.Single(s => s.ID == "META");
            Assert.IsTrue(actual.IsInitialized);
        }
        else
            throw new Exception("The Database was not seeded correctly for the test");
    }
```

In order to test my custom Initializer I made a class that inherits from it I could use the Seed() method to make some data I could test against. This is the class:

```
    //class is derived from class that needs to be tested so can still be used for testing
    //this class adds seed data to check the database with
    public class CustomDropCreateDatabaseWithMatchingModelTest 
        : CustomDropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<POSDatabaseContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(POSDatabaseContext context)
        {
            //if metadata exist (Which it should since the database
            //shouldn't be dropped because the model is the same)
            if(context.Metadata.Any(s => s.ID == "META"))
            {
                Metadata meta = context.Metadata.Single(s => s.ID == "META");
                if(meta.IsInitialized == true)
                    throw new Exception("The database has not been dropped"+
                        " and recreated correctly during the unit test setup."
                    );
                else
                {
                    meta.IsInitialized = true;
                    meta.TimeEdited = DateTime.Now;
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
            else
                throw new Exception("Metadata not found. The database was"+
                    " either dropped because it was falsely accused of not"+
                    " having a matching model, OR the database was not seeded"+
                    " properly during unit test setup."
                    );
        }
    }
```

And the class it was derived from:

```
//This file contains custom versions of the built in
//database intializer classes in which an SQL Statement
//is run to stop all connections to the database so that
//when the database is dropped, a database in use
//exception is not thrown.
public class CustomDropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<Context> 
    : IDatabaseInitializer<Context> where Context : DbContext
{
    public void InitializeDatabase(Context context)
    {
        if (context.Database.Exists())
        {
            if (!context.Database.CompatibleWithModel(true))
            {
                string query = "ALTER DATABASE [POS] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;";
                context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(TransactionalBehavior.DoNotEnsureTransaction, query);
                context.Database.Delete();
                context.Database.Create();
            }
            //else do nothing and continue
        }
        else context.Database.Create();

        //run seed method
        Seed(context);
    }

    //OVERIDE ME
    //this method seeds the database with data
    protected virtual void Seed(Context context) { }
}
```

The problem I seem to be having is that the Initilization is not running until after the assert. I have checked the values of Metadata actual and the values are the values from the SetUp() method. I also checked that the object is marked as modified before SaveChanges() is called in the method that I am testing. However, the method is most certainly running because the database reflects the values from the method.

The original problem I thought I was having was that the IsInitialized property was being returned as the wrong value since it was 1 in the database but I was getting false in the code.

Comment: Have you tried to setup another boolean property? This may lead to an insight if you missed anything the first time around.

Comment: I was thinking about doing that but I'm not sure how I would use it. It's difficult because I would want it to be used differently to test it. I think.

Comment: Sorry, edited, I missed those when posting the code. The string is the same in my code.

Comment: Could u check the status of the object after changing the property  (`Context.Entry<SomeObject>(someObject).State;`) but before you call SaveChanges() ? Is it in a modified state or unchanged ?

Comment: @Whoami It says it's modified.

Comment: I added TestBool to the class. I seed it as true for the test and don't change it in the function I call. It returns the correct value. I am working on making a more exact post, I think the function might be getting called after I get the values. It's a database initializer. I guess I should have put that in my original post, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `Assert.AreEqual(true,` into `Assert.IsTrue(`, because `true` can have different forms between types. As you noticed, it was encoded `1` in the database, which may not match exactly.

You can check if the `SaveChanges()` updates the context before the Assert properly: do an Assertion on `TimeEdited` first. (Replace DateTime.Now with some constant value that compares more easily first).

Comment: I am outputting to the console with the boolean value and it is false. So the first part is not why its not working but I will start using that format regardless. For the second part I think you may be right.

Comment: Okay, so I replaced DateTime.Now with DateTime.UTC. Just before the assert, it is still DateTime.Now but in the database it is DateTime.UTC after the test. So the method I am testing is running, but not before the assert and I am not sure why. I should probably post my full code now, how should I go about that? I am not sure I want to edited my original post so the question doesn't change and the rest of the comments don't look out of context.

Comment: You now probably have a synchronization problem. You may assert against the old database value. Retrieve it from the database again, but you may also need to refresh the local copy of database.

Answer (score 0):

At the top of my test class I have:

```
[TestFixture]
public class CustomDropCreateDatabaseIfModelChangesTest
{
    protected const string connectionString = 
        "Data Source=SABERTOOTH\\POS;Initial Catalog=POS;Integrated Security=true;Pooling=false";
    protected POSDatabaseContext database;

....

}
```

I have have changed the test to use a new DbContext as so:

```
    [Test]
    public void InitializeDatabaseTestWithMatchingModel()
    {
        //set initializer for data context to test it, and run it
        Database.SetInitializer<POSDatabaseContext>(new CustomDropCreateDatabaseWithMatchingModelTest());
        database.Database.Initialize(true);

        POSDatabaseContext newContext = new POSDatabaseContext(connectionString);

        //use the metata table to check if it was run correctly
        //if metadata exist, which it should
        if(newContext.Metadata.Any(s => s.ID == "META"))
        {
            Metadata actual = newContext.Metadata.Single(s => s.ID == "META");

            Assert.IsTrue(actual.IsInitialized);
        }
        else
            throw new Exception("The Database was not seeded correctly");         
    }
```

So it turns out that Pieter21 was correct the context wasn't getting refreshed for some reason and a new context had to be made. I am not sure why however.